# number of items to replace is not a multiple of , MonteCarlo Stochastic Process R error

Tags: simulation, numerical-methods, montecarlo, numerical-integration, stochastic-process

```
##
set.seed(123)
SimpleEulerApproximation = function(T,x,a,b,delta){
  numberofSteps = T/delta;
  TimeSteps = rep(numberofSteps,1);
  Y = rep(numberofSteps,1)
  Y[1] = x;
  for (i in 1:numberofSteps){
    TimeSteps[i] = 0 + i*delta;
  }
  for (j in 2:numberofSteps){
    Y[j] = Y[j-1] + a*Y[j-1]*delta + b*Y[j-1]*rnorm(1,0,sqrt(delta));
  }
  ##plot(TimeSteps,Y, type = "l")
  
}
SimpleEulerApproximation(1,20,-0.01,0.25,0.001)

set.seed(123)

MultipleEulerApproximation = function(T,x,a,b,delta,numberofTrajectories){
  numberofSteps = round(T/delta);
  TimeSteps = rep(numberofSteps,1);
  Y = rep(numberofSteps,rep(numberofTrajectories))
  Y = data.matrix(Y)
  for (i in 1:numberofTrajectories){
    Y[,i] = SimpleEulerApproximation(T,x,a,b,delta);
  }
  for (i in 1:numberofSteps){
    TimeSteps[i] =  0 + i*delta;
  }
  AverageTrajectory = rep(numberofSteps,1)
  for (i in 1:numberofSteps){
    AverageTrajectory[i] = mean(Y[i,])
  }
  ##plot(TimeSteps,AverageTrajectory)
}
MultipleEulerApproximation(1,52,0.12,0.30,0.0001,10000)

MonteCarloSimulation = function(T,x,r,sigma,K,delta,numberofTrajectories){
  Y = MultipleEulerApproximation(T,x,r,sigma,delta,numberofTrajectories);
  lastStep = round(T/delta);
  max(Y[lastStep,]-K,0);
  size(Y)
  price = 1/numberofTrajectories * sum(max(Y[lastStep,]-K,0))*exp(-r*T)
}
MonteCarloSimulation(0.25,52,0.12,0.3,50,0.0001,10000)
```

When I run the code for multipleEulerApproximation, I get replacement has length 0 error. Can someone help me with this? Much Appreciated.
The first one is simple Euler Approximation for stochastic differential equation dXt =
−0.1Xtdt + 0.25XtdBt, X0 = 20 over the time interval [0, 1] with time step size
∆ = 0.001.
The second chunk of code is for multipleeulerapproximation that is where the error.
The third-chunk is for calculating European call option price using projections.